# applescript - cannot make into type number

Tags: string, numbers, applescript

Why won't this simple Applescript snippet work?

```
set x to 0
set thePath to "~/Pictures/party hard/b93-" + x + ".png"
```

I get the error:

```
Can’t make "~/Pictures/party hard/b93-" into type number.
```

I've tried a lot of other things, like `(x as string)`.

It's so simple, and I don't understand why it won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AppleScript’s concatenation operator is `&`, while `+` is interpreted literally. It throws an error because your code is attempting to add a string and a number together.

Try this:

```
set x to 0
set thePath to "~/Pictures/party hard/b93-" & x & ".png"
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm just used to programming in other languages, I haven't used Applescript in a while.